# How to share a DbCOntext in n-tier repository pattern. Asp .net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, repository-pattern, dbcontext

Firstly i must say, i know their is a very close question i found on stackoverflow, but my question is a little different.

I have **n-tier application** in asp .net mvc, in which I have: 
A **BOL** project(which has EF classes and db object etc),  
**BLL** project(which has buiseness logic), 
than we have **DAL** project(which has db interaction logic, and it uses EF dbcontext from BOL). 
And a **main mvc project** which ahs controllers and views etc.

Now, **we are using repository pattern**, we have **many Repositories in BLL with their interfaces**. And also we have **many repositories in DAL which are without interfaces though**. But **all of those DAL repositories have one DbContext member in them**, which is being created in their constructors, so **each DAL repository is interacting with separate instance of DbContext which it has created.**

And in our main mvc project, we have **used ninject to inject BLL repositories in controllers constructors** (in request scope). Now, **the issue** we are facing is, that each BLL repository has references to one or more DAL repositories, and **each of those DAL repositories are using their own seperate DbCOntext. Which is wrong and bad, thats why i am looking for the way to share one DbCOntext in all DAL repositories, per request(No matter how many BLL repositories ninject injects in my controller, just make sure only one DbContext instance is being created and used per request). And dispose that context after each request.**

**One way i thought** was to not create DBcontext in constructor of DAL repositories. But have some method call(say initiateDbContext) for that, than also add this method in BLL repositories, which do nothing but to call the smae method of their member DAL repositories. Call that method for **one** BLL repository in controller constructor, and than have a method to get and set db contexts in all other repositories from the first repository. But i know this is bad approach, firstly we are creating DbContext in controller, which should be in DAL only, secondly i am adding create, get and set DbCOntext methods in DAL as well as in BLL repositories, because i need to pass DbCOntext to BLL which will pass that to the DAL repositories it communicates with internally. And that's very bad.

That's why i am asking here for **any good pattern to achieve "ONE DBCONTEXT PER REQUEST IN N-TIER WITH REPOSITORY PATTERN."**

Comment: All the random bolding of words doesn't really make your question any more readable.

Comment: @CodeCaster I know my question doesnot make a lot of sense, but i TRIED to highlight some important points, so it might be easy to understand. Maybe you can suggest something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Based on the answer from @atika** i searched further and implemented what he suggested(using ninject/DI in whole application rather than just in one main project of mvc) and it solved the issue, **i am posting this answer to add more details and some extra issues i faced and i got to spend time googling about further, so others might save some time.**

Idea is to use dependency injection throughout the solution, no matter how many projects/tiers you have in it and no matter how many repositories you have got.

So, the issue comes to the point, that **if we want to use ninject or any other DI for binding all dependencies from all tiers/projects, we should have reference to all of those tiers/projects in our main mvc project, so that we can bind the dependencies in NinjectWebCommons, but this will kill the whole purpose of n-tier architecture. We don't want to do that**, we want our hierarchy to sustain, like in my case
**MainMVCProject->BLL->DLL->DB**

So, **for this, i found a very helpful article** [Ninject with N-Tier MVC Application - Inject Object in Business Layer](http://myseesharp.blogspot.com/2015/01/ninject-with-n-tier-mvc-application_1.html).(Their are also some other approaches, one is to make a project just for bindings and add use that project to bind all dependencies, but that sounds like over engineering and overkill)

Based on which i added the following class in my BLL tier/project(after installing ninject in this project and DAL project too), which has bindings for DLL classes.

```
using BLL.Repositories;
using BLL.RepositoryInterfaces;
using Ninject.Modules;
using Ninject.Web.Common;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DAL;
using BOL;

namespace BLL
{
    public class LayerBindings : NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {//add all references here like these
            Bind<AdDb>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
            Bind<db_Entities>().ToSelf().InRequestScope().WithConstructorArgument("ConnectionString", BOL.CommonFunctionsBOL.ConnectionString);
        }
    }
}
```

Getting some help from [howto-ninject-part-1-basics](https://lukewickstead.wordpress.com/2013/02/09/howto-ninject-part-1-basics/) article, i managed to do many things with ninject, and used many of its features.

Now, you can see **i added the bindings of DLL project in this class, which were not accessible in main mvc project. Now, i just need to load these bindings in main ninject.
Now, in NinjectWebCommons.cs file, i added following lines:**

```
//old bindings of BLL and local project.    
kernel.Bind<IUserRepository>().To<UserRepository>().InRequestScope();
//now here we bind other dependencies of DAL etc using class we added in BLL
var modules = new List<INinjectModule>
{
      new BLL.LayerBindings()
};
kernel.Load(modules);
```

(In **RegisterServices** method, after local bindings and BLL objects bindings.)

After doing just this, ninject started working in all the projects and i just used constructor injection or on some places, property injections and all worked fine.

**PS1:** I also used **property injection***(i read that this is not recommended to use property injections, use them only where you cant use constructor injections.)* for private properties and they had to be enabled with kernel.Settings.InjectNonPublic = true; line in "CreateKernel" method before returning the kernal.
Now my property injection is working for private properties too, like this:

```
[Ninject.Inject]
private SomeDALObject db { get; set; }
```

**PS2:** I also installed **ninject.web.webapi** nuget package for ninject to work with webapis, and also **found this line to get an object anywhere from ninjec**t.(*I don't know if this is a good way or not, but it does return a fully constructed object which i used than. If any one can clarify or correct me if using this is right or not, that will be great.*)

```
((TypeOfObjectYouWant)System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(TypeOfObjectYouWant))).DoSomething();
```

I hope this might help some people like me looking for proper guide on this issue.

Comment: Thanks @Zia made it really easy for future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using dependency injection, you should use it all the way, not only in the controllers.
That means, the DBContext should be injected into the Repositories, and Ninject should be configured to resolve your DBContext with per request lifetime.

Comment: Makes sense, it means i should include ninject in my DAL project, and all of my repositories should be getting injected the dependencies they need, BLL repositories should receive DAL injected, and DAL repositories should receive DbCOntext injected in them by ninject. This makes perfect sense, but i have never used ninject in this kind of layered architecture thing. What should i google to get some info on this. I mean what is terminology for this.

Comment: The first hit for "ninject multiple layers" looks like a good starting point. I am not very familiar with Ninject, but I see that it has support for modules. That's what I'm using with Autofac, every layer has it's own module and it's loaded by the layer above it. Makes layer separation very easy to implement.

Comment: Alright, i am looking into it, and i should say i am new to it, so i might catch up in case of any more confusions. Thank you for your answer. I will mark accepted as soon as my issue is resolved.

Comment: @DilipN actually didn't find DI in your example actually.

Comment: @atika can you please have a look at this example and give me a go? As i told you i am new to this type of injection, so i am rather confused. This example makes perfect sense to me, just verify it. Thankyou again for your help. http://myseesharp.blogspot.com/2015/01/ninject-with-n-tier-mvc-application_1.html

Comment: @atika thanks atika, i am now going to implement it, seems like it will resolve the issue. I will update here about that. And of-course accept your answer.

Comment: @atika now i am confused on whether i should mark this answer as accepted or my detailed answer below which is based on your answer. I posted that answer to add details which i had to explore my self after your guidance, so others might save some time. But your answer was the direction. Tell me what to do :D

Comment: Not sure what the SO guidelines recommend in this case, but yours being the more detailed answer, I think it's ok to mark that as accepted.

Answer (score -1):

```
  You can write one BaseRepository and implement BaseRepository in all     repository classes.

public class BaseRepository
    {
        public StudentEntities  dbStudentEntity;

        public BaseRepository()
        {
            dbStudentEntity = new StudentEntities();
        }
    }

DataRepository :

public class CurrencyData : BaseRepository,ICurrencyData
    {
        public List<Models.Currency> GetCurrencyList()
        {
            var objCurrencies = dbStudentEntity.Currencies.ToList();
            List<Models.Currency> currencyList = new     List<Models.Currency>();

             foreach (var item in objCurrencies)
            {
                var model = new Models.Currency { CurrencyId =     item.CurrencyId, Currency1 = item.Currency1,Code = item.Code,Symbol =     item.Symbol,Country = item.Country };
                currencyList.Add(model);
            }
            return currencyList;
         }

     }
```

Comment: will it not be the case that still each repository will get new instance of base repository, i.e each repository will have different Context again? Because each repository will inherit from BaseRepository?

Comment: @Dilip N This is not what OP asked for, please reconsider your answer